# Syntax highlights for variable names in declaration

Tags: listings, syntax-highlighting

I'm using a language whose pretty printing highlights variables when defined with their type. So if I write:

```
Fun foo (a: int):
```

Then `Fun` and `int` will be highlighted in blue (they are defined keyword), but `a` will be highlighted in green (it's a newly defined variable).

I don't want to define `a` as keyword, obviously. Is there a way to give listings some parsing power to notice that it's a variable definition?

Is there any way to do this with the listings package?

Similarly, many syntax highlighters would change the color of `foo` (for every definition declaration). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: I don't see what I'm looking for there. Could you explain?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Is this a (well-)known programming language? If yes then you might find an existing highlighting specification for it, for `listings` or (more likely) for `minted`.